# Html string with <style> tag and style in android textview

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, textview

I'm trying to show display an html string in a textview. I used the Html.fromhtml method to load html string textview. But It failed to parse  tag. Here is my html string

```
<style>u.style{color:#FF0000;}span.style2{color:#000000;}</style>
<u class="style"><span class="style2">some text</span></u>
```

I had tried Spannable String also, But It displays underline and underlined text in same color.I don't want to change text color.

```
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Can anyone help me to create custom textview, which can support  tag in textview?

Comment: In this you are using CSS.  CSS is not supported in android, if you want to use then Use Html.fromHtml("Your Text in tags");

Comment: I had used this method. But I am looking for custom textview, which can support css also.

Comment: TextView is not support style tag so try to load on WebView.

Comment: It could work if you use <font color='#000000;'>some text</font>

Comment: @Roshni I think you need to use WebView instead of TextView to make it easier. Just design your webview exactly same like TextView.

Comment: In case of Textview it doesnt support style tag for html. So you cannot use font-family in textview. Instead create a webview instance and load this string on webview.

Answer (score 9):

for html you must use this :

```
mytext.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

also check this link 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29

and This is a list of allowed HTML tags:

```
br
p
div
em
b
strong
cite
dfn
i
big
small
font
blockquote
tt
monospace
a
u
sup
sub
```

Comment: Does this support inline styling? Say `<p style='margin: 0; color: #ff0000;'>This is a paragraph.</p>`

Comment: No, just support above tag.

Answer (score 4):

The `style` and `span` tags are not supported in `TextView`.

What you can do is this:

```
String myHtmlString = Html.fromHtml("<u> <font color=\"#FF0000\"> some text </font> </u>");
```

FYI, [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) is a list of supported tags.

Answer (score 1):

you should have to use like this

```
String styledText = "This is <font color='red'>simple</font>.";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: It will display underline and underlined text in same color.