# Is there a way to overline text in android studio (java)

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio

I am trying to display square roots in my java mobile aplication. I tried with HTML by typing the code below. It displays the square root symbol but there is no line over the variable (√100). Is there a way to overline the variable (x). Thanks for your help :)
`TextView.settext(Html.fromHtml("&#x221A "+x));`

Answer (score 0):

You can try StrikethroughSpan like this:

```
textView.setText(x.toString(), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable spannable = (Spannable) textView;
spannable.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, 3, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing math formulas in Android might most easily be done by using a web view and then using MathML. For instance:

```html
    <math>
      <msqrt>
        <mn>100</mn>
      </msqrt>
    </math>
```

should show a well-formatted mathematical expression consisting of a square root of 100.

You can try it out here:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GFAL3VTCXMCU

and then click run.

WebView and MathML may be overkill for your purposes, however, and it may also be a good idea to read or skim through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Authoring as well as the drawbacks of using a WebView.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I am afraid, this has not worked for me:

`<SPAN STYLE="text-decoration:overline">here the text has overline.</SPAN>`

The suggestion may come from here?: https://html-shark.com/HTML/Overline.htm

I also came across this one which provides some more information on html supported tags:
[Html string with <style> tag and style in android textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011611/html-string-with-style-tag-and-style-in-android-textview/25011685)

The overline span style seems to require css which is according to above linked discussion (unfortunately) not supported in Android.

The work around with the xml background line looks like a good looking solution but also did not work for me - I need overlined words randomly in strings.

Not looking perfect, but I have used overline each individual character instead now. However, this can leave gaps between different overlines. For example, to overline every character in the word 'Test', use:

`editText.setText(Html.fromHtml("T&#773;e&#773;s&#773;t&#773;"));`

other overline options on wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline

May work for others as well...

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do it with a little workaround from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36003054) answer.

Here is how it can be done for anyone coming later to this question

**Step 1:** Create a drawable file and name it whatever you wish to, in this case I am naming it as **overline.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="-2dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#030310" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Step 2:** Add the overline.xml as a background onto your TextView with `android:background="@drawable/overline`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/overline"
    android:textColor="#030310"
    android:text="Hello"/>
```

Result:

[image]